# Suggestions on MySQL query with multiple OR operators

Tags: mysql, database, bigdata, data-analysis, rdbms

I want to perform a MySQL query on a large table (500+ million rows). A particular column has thousands of possible element values I want to return all the rows where this column is just 100 of these values.

Lets say this `column1` can have these values: `A1, A2, A3, .., A12309`. I want to do a query like so:

```
SELECT column2 WHERE column1='A1' OR column1='A2'... OR column1='A100'
```

Having 100 different OR operators is highly inefficient.

**Is there a better way to structure this query?**

Is MySQL suited for this or is there a better DBMS / data analysis tool?

Comment: Consider creating a table containing the values to be selected and join to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column2  FROM tbl
    WHERE column1 IN ('A1', 'A2', ... 'A100')
```

This will work reasonably well for 100 values.

This should help, too:

```
INDEX(column1, column2)
```

Which version of MySQL?  (Some versions have a cutoff -- above some number of values in the `IN` leads to a less efficient execution plan, especially for 500M rows.)